# Whats the "Params" keyword in method parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, default

Whats the "Default" keyword in this method?

```
public IEnumerable<T> createEmpty(Object key)
{
    foreach (var item in MyCollection)
    {
        T element = new T(); 
        element = default(T);
        yield return element;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the title different from the question?

Comment: How about reading some c# docs? Google is smart enough, even if you type your title, it brings the answer in the first result

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does default(object); do in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432909/what-does-defaultobject-do-in-c). Please take some time to Google your question before asking.

Comment: @tnw thanks for editing my answer, i didn't notice that mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean the "Default" keyword?

Question already answered here: [What does default(object); do in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432909/what-does-defaultobject-do-in-c)

Thats only a method that returns the default value for that type, for example:

```
Int32 number = default(Int32); // returns 0
Object myObject = default(Object); // returns null
bool flag = default(bool);  // return false
```