# 'System.NullReferenceException'

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing a `LINQ` query. But, i am getting `null object reference error` for `Model.StudentSummary.StudentDetails`.

I put breakpoint on following `foreach` and when i mouse over `Model.StudentSummary.StudentDetails` i see `StudentDetails` is `null`.

I have initialized the whole model class than why it didn't initialize `List<StudentDetails>` in `StudentSummary` class?

```
foreach (Summary summary in Model.summaryData)
{
    Model.StudentSummary.StudentDetails.Add(new SafetyDetails
    {
        Name = summary.Name,
        ManTimeWorked = summary.TotalTime,
    });
}
```

Model.cs

```
public class Report : BaseReportModel
{
    public Report()
    {
      StudentSummary = new StudentSummary();
    }
    public StudentSummary StudentSummary { get; set; }
}

public class StudentSummary
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<StudentDetails> StudentDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Because reference types - like `List` - default to null.

Comment: `StudentSummary`'s `StudentDetails` is not set.

Comment: A property that is a reference type will be `null` unless set to an existing object reference or allocated with `new`

Comment: But i initialized StudentSummary class than shouldn't it also initialize list?

Comment: @immirza *no*, it won't. Reference types are `null` until set with an existing object reference or allocated with `new`. You may want a `StudentSummary` constructor that sets `StudentDetails = new List<StudentDetails>();`. (just like your `Report` constructor allocates a `new StudentSummary();`).

Comment: No, initializing StudentSumary only initializes the reference to the list (to null).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because you initialized the object doesn't mean that all of its properties are initialized: each of those carries its default value until you change it, and the `default` for a `List` (or any `class`-type object) is `null` (more details in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432909/what-does-defaultobject-do-in-c)). You need to initialize the list.

You can inline this in your `Report` constructor like:

```
public class Report : BaseReportModel
{
    public Report()
    {
        StudentSummary = new StudentSummary
        {
            StudentDetails = new List<StudentDetails>()
        }
    }
    public StudentSummary StudentSummary { get; set; }
}
```

Another option is to initialize it in `StudentSummary`'s constructor itself, which keeps the class in a nice state from the beginning without any additional work:

```
public class StudentSummary
{
    public StudentSummary()
    {
        StudentDetails = new List<StudentDetails>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<StudentDetails> StudentDetails { get; set; }
}
```

This has a tradeoff: if you already *have* a `List<StudentDetails>` that you want to initialize it to, you needlessly create a new list - but if your regular use case is adding them as you do in the example code, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Or even better, do this in the constructor of StudentSummary and stop the class from being initialised in an invalid state :)

Comment: Maybe cleaner to do that in a `constructor`?

Comment: @eouw0o83hf, thanks make sense. good point

Answer (score 1):

If you're expecting StudentSummary.StudentDetails to be instantiated at the same time as StudentSummary you need to manually do it in the StudentSummary constructor, as you do with the StudentSummary in the Report constructor.