# For a database collection, should FirstOrDefault return null?

Tags: linq

I am puzzled by the expected behaviour or the family of LINQ methods `SingleOrDefault`, `FirstOrDefault`, `LastOrDefault` and `ElementAtOrDefault` methods, operating on a database.

Should they return:

1. null, or
2. a new object populated with default values?

Comment: they return [`default(T)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432909/what-does-defaultobject-do-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the **Return Value** section of [`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482)

> **default**(TSource) if *source* is empty; otherwise, the first element in *source*.

---

`default(T)` for [Reference Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2) is null in almost all cases, but for [Value Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch) is not null. Examples:

```
int i; // 0
var j = default(int);    // 0
var b = default(bool);   // false
var s = default(string); // null
var s = default(object); // null

var i0 = (new    int[] { }).FirstOrDefault(); // 0 
var s0 = (new string[] { }).FirstOrDefault(); // null
```

There is also [`DefaultIfEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419):

```
var i1 = new int[] { }.DefaultIfEmpty(-1).ToArray(); // { -1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

They return the item in the sequence or the `default` value of the item if the sequence is empty (or in the case of 'ElementAtOrDefault' if the index specified is out of range).

The below excerpt is from the documentation for `default`:

> The solution is to use the default keyword, which will return null for
>   reference types and zero for numeric value types. For structs, it will
>   return each member of the struct initialized to zero or null depending
>   on whether they are value or reference types.

Link to `default` documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here are some definition's using reflector.

**FirstOrDefault**

```
public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
    if (list != null)
    {
        if (list.Count > 0)
        {
            return list[0];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                return enumerator.Current;
            }
        }
    }
    return default(TSource);
}
```

**SingleOrDefault**

```
    public static TSource SingleOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        }
        IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
        if (list != null)
        {
            switch (list.Count)
            {
                case 0:
                    return default(TSource);

                case 1:
                    return list[0];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
            {
                if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    return default(TSource);
                }
                TSource current = enumerator.Current;
                if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    return current;
                }
            }
        }
        throw Error.MoreThanOneElement();
    }
```

**LastOrDefault**

```
    public static TSource LastOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        }
        IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
        if (list != null)
        {
            int count = list.Count;
            if (count > 0)
            {
                return list[count - 1];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
            {
                if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    TSource current;
                    do
                    {
                        current = enumerator.Current;
                    }
                    while (enumerator.MoveNext());
                    return current;
                }
            }
        }
        return default(TSource);
    }
```

**ElementAtOrDefault**

```
public static TSource ElementAtOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int index)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        }
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
            if (list != null)
            {
                if (index < list.Count)
                {
                    return list[index];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
                {
                    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        if (index == 0)
                        {
                            return enumerator.Current;
                        }
                        index--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return default(TSource);
    }
```

Comment: The source code is also available here for Enumerable: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs , and here for IQueryable: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/IQueryable.cs