# Default Value of a dictionary and FirstOrDefault() in LINQ mismatch

Tags: c#, linq, default-value

Why default value of a dictionary class is not same as default value returned by FirstOrDefault using LINQ?

```
Dictionary<Mode, string> myDict = new Dictionary<Mode, string>() { { Mode.First, "ValueFirst" }, { Mode.Second, "ValueSecond" }, { Mode.Third, "ValueThird" }, { Mode.Forth, "ValueForth" } };
var r1 = myDict.Where(d => d.Value == "Do not exist").FirstOrDefault();
var r2 = default(Dictionary<Mode, string>);
```

Here Mode is an enum. As a result, r1 is a key-value pair with default values, but r2 is null. Why?

Comment: Because `FirstOrDefault()` returns a `KeyValuePair`. Not a dictionary.

Comment: Or, it can return `default(KeyValuePair)`, which is null - always watch out for nulls on `FirstOrDefault()`.  That's related to your second question (about `r2`).  If you are working with a reference type (like a `Dictionary`), then `default(YourReferenceTypeGoesHere)` is null - it's always null.  If you use `default` on a value type, then it's the zero-ish value, but for reference types, it's always `null`

Comment: `KeyValuePair<,>` is a struct, it can never be null. Unless we are talking about Nullable<KeyValuePair<,>>` which is another type.

Comment: @Xiaoy312: Ooops!  Didn't look it up.  Makes sense for it to be a value type.  Thanks!  I've spent a lot of time over the past year cleaning up messes where co-workers called Whatever().FirstOrDefault() and then used the results without a null-check.  It's one of my go to code review issues now.

Comment: `var r1 = myDict.Where(d => d.Value == "Do not exist").FirstOrDefault();` This is a terrible idea. You can't distinguish whether there was really an entry there or not. If you want to know whether an entry was there you **must** use `ContainsKey` or `TryGetValue`. Or use (worse) `var r1 = myDict.Where(d => d.Value == "Do not exist").Cast<KeyValuePair<Mode, string>?>.FirstOrDefault();` so you can get `null` (which clearly means 'it wasn't there').

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does default(object); do in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432909/what-does-defaultobject-do-in-c)

Answer (score -1):

Use `default(KeyValuePair<,>)` to check for default value:

```
var kvp = dict.FirstOrDefault(...);
if (default(KeyValuePair<Mode, string>).Equals(kvp))
```

Alternatively, you could use an extension method here:

```
public static class KeyValuePairExtensions
{
    public static bool IsDefault<TKey, TValue>(this KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kvp) => default(KeyValuePair<Mode, string>).Equals(kvp);
}

// usage
var kvp = dict.FirstOrDefault(...);
if (kvp.IsDefault())
```