# Return default value of generic parameter

Tags: typescript, generics

Coming from C#. How do we return default value of generic parameter in Typescript? For example here is an utterly useless function in C#:

```
private T TwiceAsMuch<T>(T number)
{
  if (number is int n)
    return (T)(object)(n * 2);
  else if (number is float f)
    return (T)(object)(f * 2);
  else
    return default;
}
```

How do I achieve this last line `return default` in Typescript?

### Context

I'm writing a little wrapper function that performs `axios.post` and returns the response in the type specified by the caller:

```
private static async postInternal<T>(route: string, data: unknown): Promise<T> {
  await Vue.$axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')
  const res = await Vue.$axios.post<T>(`${route}`, data)
    .then(res => res.data)
    .catch(err => {
      openErr(err)
      return ???
    })
}
```

What goes in place of `???`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to say there is no equivalent. A value has a type, but a type may never have a value, default or otherwise.

I know nothing of C#, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2432945/62076) `return default` does this:

> `default` keyword will return `null` for reference types and zero for numeric value types.

This pattern does not exist in Typescript. Unlike C#, Typescript transpiles to javascript. And javascript has no static typing. That means that at runtime, you cannot know the type of `T`. It's *completely* gone from the executing code.

This typescript:

```
postInternal<number>('/path', { data: true })
```

And this typescript:

```
postInternal<{ a: { b: { c: number } } }>('/path', { data: true })
```

Both compile to this javascript:

```
postInternal('/path', { data: true })
```

Which means the type of `T` *cannot* be known at runtime. Therefore you cannot branch your code path based on the type of `T` alone.

---

Typically the way you would handle this case is to allow the result to be nullable, and then just return `null` in the error case:

```
private static async postInternal<T>(route: string, data: unknown): Promise<T | null> {
  //...
}

const num = postInternal<number>('/path', { data: true }) ?? 0
```

Or by simply throwing the error and letting the caller catch it and handle what to do from there.

```
try {
  const num = postInternal<number>('/path', { data: true })
} catch (error) {
  console.error('exploded :(', error)
}
```